# Emails not sent via google smtp

Tags: php, html, email, email-attachments

I'm using the following php code to send an email with an attachment to a predefined mail.

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = $_POST['message'];
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = "dimal.chandrasiri@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "****";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SetFrom('dimal.chandrasiri@gmail.com', 'Your name');
$mail->AddReplyTo("dimal.chandrasiri@gmail.com","Your name");
$mail->Subject    = "Abstract submission for" .$_POST['fname'];
$mail->AltBody    = $_POST['message'];

if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) && $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']);
}

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = 'dimal.chandrasiri@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);

if($mail->Send()) {
      echo 'done';
} else {
      echo 'error';
}

?>
```

The passwords and other smtp details are correct but I'm unable to send any mail. What am I doing wrong here? I use the following html form to post the data.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="abstract-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="/script/submit.php">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name='fname' class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name='lname' class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name='email' class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address">
        <label>File</label>
        <input type="file" name='file' class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Abstract File">
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>
<p> </p>    
</form>
```

I get the following error when I echo the error info.

```
The following From address failed: dimal.chandrasiri@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Comment: This code is worked before ?or not ?

Comment: `echo $mail->ErrorInfo`

Comment: I took the code from a tutorial for a testing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: can you login using this email from the browser?have you tested this code with another email(google or other account)?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail users can access their account on the official website or by using first-party or third-party apps and services instead. A first party app is for instance Google's official Gmail app for Android, while Thunderbird and the mail client app of Windows 8 are third-party apps.

Google [announced](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html) back in April 2014 that it would improve the sign-in security of its services and affect any application sending usernames and passwords to the company.

The company suggested to switch to OAuth 2.0 back then but did not enforce it up until now.

If you open the new [less secure](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) apps page under security settings on Google, you will notice that Google has disabled access by default.

Note: You see the page only if you are not using Google Apps or have enabled two-factor authentication for the account.

**You can flip the switch here to enable less secure applications again so that access is regained.**

[image]

Comment: I switched this off and tested! still the same issue!

Comment: Did you mean you switch to Enable or Disable ?

Comment: I disabled this feature enabling me to send emails via google!

Comment: You must choose Access for less secure apps ==> ENABLE the second one this what i mean and test it again

Comment: Did you want to test a vbscript that use Gmail just for testing ?